# bottom aligned content inside link

Tags: html, css

I have a simple link in HTML

```
<a href="#">this is a link</a>
```

and this is the CSS

```
a {
    height: 500px;
    outline: 1px #000 dotted;
}
```

I can´t push the content to the bottom of the link. It can´t be that hard right?

this is how it looks

```
...................
. this is a link  .
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
...................
```

this is what I need

```
...................
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
. this is a link  .
...................
```

Comment: a is an inline element so you cannot give it a height ... you need to first make it block or inline-block and then you have a lot of duplicates ...

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```css
a {
    height: 100px;
    outline: 1px #000 dotted;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
a {
height: 500px;
position: relative;
outline: 1px #000 dotted;
display: block;
}
a span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

add a span like this

```
<a href="#"><span>this is a link</span></a>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px dotted #000;
  top: 20px;
}
```